# How to move a file download from configure step to build step?

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have the block below in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
file (DOWNLOAD http://.../file.zip "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/file.zip")
execute_process (
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E tar -xf file.zip
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
add_custom_command (
  OUTPUT output.txt
  COMMAND "${MY_COMMAND}" file-found-in-zip.txt output.txt
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

The basic steps are:

1. Download.
2. Extract.
3. Add a custom command that uses a file that was extracted in step 2.

During the build step, the custom command may or may not be executed, but the download and extraction always will. How can I make the download and extraction conditional, such that it happens only if the custom command that needs it will be executed?

Comment: So remove `execute_process` and do `add_custom_command` and add dependencies between two commands? And remove `FILE(DOWNLOAD...` instead to `add_custom_command` to download the file.

Comment: Do you mind turning that into an answer? How to "add dependencies between two commands"? Can you explain the details please? `file(DOWNLOAD ...)` doesn't have a `cmake -E` equivalent; is my only option to create _another_ script file and use `cmake -P`?

Comment: Sure, good idea to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something along:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/download.cmake 
    "file(DOWNLOAD http://.../file.zip ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.zip"
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.zip
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/download.cmake
    VERBATIM
)
execute_process (
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file-found-in-zip.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.zip
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar -xf file.zip
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file-found-in-zip.txt
    COMMAND "${MY_COMMAND}" file-found-in-zip.txt output.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)
```

Or just:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/download.cmake 
    "file(DOWNLOAD http://.../file.zip ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.zip"
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/download.cmake
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar -xf file.zip
    COMMAND "${MY_COMMAND}" file-found-in-zip.txt output.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
```